# Permanently add value in combobox

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have this part of code that, after I run a macro that create a new column, add the last column letter in a combobox

```
ColumnLetter = Split(Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(5, 0), "$")(0)

Worksheets("Sheet1").CB1.AddItem ColumnLetter
```

Works great but once I close the file the record disappear, exist a solution to keep this data in a permanent way?

Comment: record disappear? It seems you do not want the combobox to be empty when the file is opened again. You can use [Workbook_Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) event to fill the combobox values. So, you will not see empty commbobox once the event procedure is immediately run after workbook is opened.

Comment: but in this way i need to know the list of all filled column, in my way i fill the combobox value meanwhile i find it.
Another way may be spell the column letter, it's possibile do something like:

for column = G to ColumnLetter

Comment: @chuck22 If you want to loop though columns you need to use their numbers. For example `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")` is the same as `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)` So you can do a  `For i = 1 To 5` and use the column number. Btw. Did you see my answer below?

Comment: If you want the combobox to be filled when you open the workbook, you can populate it using Workbook_Open Event. If during the process you add other columns, you can add column letter to the combobox with a macro or Worksheet_Change event procedure. Not clear from your question/ comments whats the purpose.

Comment: yes, but in my case it's not applicable because i don't have the possibilities to add other sheets.

Comment: @NareshBhople the purpose is permit to the final user to choose a certain column and, via vba macro, lock this.
Obviusly if you would suggest me a smarter way to do this it would be great for me :-)

Comment: Well if you cannot save it in a worksheet, then there is the only option to fill the combobox on every `Workbook_Open` again. Therefore you would need to put the code that fills your combobox into the `Workbook_Open` event of `ThisWorkbook`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the advice, i solved in this way

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

        Dim lastCol As Integer
        Dim ColName As String
        Set male = Worksheets("Male")
        lastCol = male.Cells(5, male.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
        male.CB1.Clear
        For i = 7 To lastCol
            ColName = Replace(Split(Columns(i).Address, ":")(0), "$", "")
            male.CB1.AddItem ColName
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim lastCol As Long` • Column counts are `Long` not `Integer`.

Comment: Thats it.  :) .. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to fill the combobox each time you open the file, or you have to store the values in a worksheet and link the combobox `Rowsource` to that data range (then it will keep the data):

Example: Store your data in a worksheet `combodata` in range A1:A50 and then set the rowsource of that combobox to `combodata!A1:A50`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that after you run a macro that create a new column and add the last column letter in a combobox, I am assuming that the combobox is already populated with present columns before the macro run.

Also, as you mentioned the once you close the file the combobox records disappear, I assume that you want the list for the present columns letters to be populated in the combobox when you open the file.

Following is the code. As suggested by Peh, paste it as Thisworkbook object code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
LCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LCol
Cols = Cols & Split(Cells(1, i).Cells.Address(5, 0), "$")(0) & ","
Next
Cols = Left(Cols, Len(Cols) - 1)

ColsArr = Split(Cols, ",")

'Aa your combobox object is named CB1
Worksheets("Male").CB1.List = ColsArr

End Sub
```

Whenever the file is opened the combobox will be populated with used column letters